# Windows Phone 7 - Steps for Authenticated Push Notifications

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, push-notification, mpns

I have looked through lots of different resources via the internet for pre-requisites and implementations of the Authenticated Push Notification mechanism for Windows Phone 7.

I have gone through:

1. [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff941099(VS.92).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff941099%28VS.92%29.aspx),
2. [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg521150(v=VS.92).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg521150%28v=VS.92%29.aspx)
3. http://csainty.blogspot.com/2011/01/wp7-authenticated-push-notifications.html

What I am after is the **exact steps** (1,2,3...) for pre-requisites and implementations of authenticated push notifications.

Also, how would this work at the time of development when we do not have an application available via the Marketplace?

Comment: Which steps are you unsure of? Do you already have unauthenticated notifications working? If not focus on them first as adding authentication is just a change at the server and some submission details when you send your app to the marketplace. For testing you can still upload your certification to the App Hub and it will be valid for some period of time to allow testing.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend downloading the [Microsoft Identity Developer Training Kit](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=c3e315fa-94e2-4028-99cb-904369f177c0)

It has an WP7 example for doing authentication and push notifications.  Its a training kit focused on claims based authentication but has a very nice wp7 training lab section which covers a lot of wp7 features.

Comment: I will check and let you know.